# Limit select2 results

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I am using the excellent [select2](http://ivaynberg.github.com/select2/) jquery plugin to select tags.

I am not able to find a way to limit the results (say to first 5 only).

My code:

```
var tags = []; // this array is filled with user's tags
$("#tags").select2({
    minimumInputLength: 2,
    placeholder: 'tags',
    tags: tags,
    tokenSeparators: [",", " "],
    closeOnSelect: false
});
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

see `maximumSelectionSize` option, if you want to limit the number of results that can be selected

Comment: In my code the select2 works fine but when I add this   $(".select2").select2({ maximumSelectionSize: 2 });
I get this error in console , "Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'select2' ".
Even though my broswer loads the select2.min.js

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
tags = tags.slice(0, 5);
```

wherever relevant in your context.

Comment: Realizing I may have misinterpreted what you want to achieve, but will leave this answer just in case.

Answer (score -1):

If you're getting results via a database call then you could edit the LIMIT statement in the SQL query. For example, this would only return the first 10 results:

```
SELECT id,categories FROM wikitags WHERE categories LIKE :term ORDER BY 
categories ASC LIMIT 0,10
```

If a remote call then appreciate the solution much trickier.